# Apply middleware when URL pattern matches in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to add a simple middleware to my project that checks if a user is allowed to access a project. My approach is:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class UserProjectFit
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ($request->is('*/projects/*')) {

            $projectUserId = DB::table('project_user')
                ->where('project_id', '=', $request->project['id'])
                ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->first();

            if (is_null($projectUserId)) {
                abort(404);
            }

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It basically works, but I have also routes like e. g. `projects/create` and here the middleware kicks in too. The idea would be that the middleware only takes action in case the URL contains the string `project` and an id, e. g. `…projects/1/…`

What would be a good way to solve that? If my approach isn't good, I am happy to read your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use authentication gates and associate them with role id. This can be done in the Authserviceprovider.

Something like this

```
    Gate::define('projects_create_access', function ($user) {
        return in_array($user->role_id, [1]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the simple approach to attach the route to every route I need it. The details are:

Route:

`Route::get('projects/{project}', 'ProjectsController@showProjectDashboard')->name('show-project-dashboard')->middleware('UserProjectFit');`

---

Middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class UserProjectFit
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $projectUserId = DB::table('project_user')
            ->where('project_id', '=', $request->project['id'])
            ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->first();

        if (is_null($projectUserId)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

---

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'UserProjectFit' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserProjectFit::class
];
```